# Im trying to restart httpd.service but i get an error

Tags: linux, apache, terminal, httpd.conf

on doing `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service` i get this error

```
[opc@xxxx ~]$ sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xeu httpd.service" for det                                                 ails.
```

`systemctl status httpd.service` shows me this

```
× httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-11-05 05:48:10 GMT; 2min 54s ago
       Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
    Process: 48848 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 48848 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Reading configuration..."
        CPU: 46ms

Nov 05 05:48:09 xxxxx systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 05 05:48:10 xxxxx systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 05 05:48:10 xxxxx systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 05 05:48:10 xxxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

and `journalctl -xeu httpd.service` shows this message

[image]

i changed the port to 80 from 443 and nothing happened